# Is it possible to retrieve the last successful task execution date during a task execution on airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

on Airflow, we currently are using the `{{ prev_execution_date_success }}` at the dag level to execute queries.

I was wondering if it was possible to have it by task (i.e. retrieving the last successful execution date of a task in particular and not of the whole DAG)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the current DAG run you can access to the task instance and look up for the previous task in success state.

```
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
from airflow.utils.state import State
ti = TaskInstance(task_id=your_task_id,
                  dag_id=your_task_id,
                  execution_date=execution_date)
prev_task_success_state = ti.get_previous_ti(state=State.SUCCESS)
```

Note that `get_previous_ti` returns `TaskInstance` object thus you can access anything related to the task.

Comment: Have you verified that this works? I am encountering an error – this method is giving the previous task from the most recent successful ***Dag*** (instead of the task itself, irrespective of the DAG).

Comment: It is indeed a bug: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/18116

Comment: @ybressler_simon My answer is from Nov 2020 - it's even before Airflow 2.0 was released. The bug report you shared is on 2.1. As explained in the issue get_previous_ti will probably be changed in future versions. If so I will update the answer accordingly. For the moment the issue seems to be a bug that Airflow needs to fix - I don't think you can work around this bug.

Comment: Agreed. I spent a bunch of time trying to use chaining to lookback, but it is very slow and can run into tons of issues. Will watch the bug.